# Setting path where we want to create file

Tags: java, file, path

i have function which prints one string in file. This functions makes new file in my project. But what i want is to create new file in my folder which is in src and is called Resources.

So it should go like this Project -> src -> resources -> ForUser.txt

I tried something like this but i got error "/src/resources/ForUser.txt";

```
private void printToFile(String toPrint)
{
    File f = new File("ForUser.txt");


    if(f.exists())
        f.delete();

    PrintWriter out = null;

    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(f,true));
        out.println(toPrint);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use File f = new File("./src/resources/ForUser.txt");

Comment: @TommySchmidt It works perfectly. Could you please explain me why did we add dot ?

Comment: a path starting with a / is called absolute. so the path /src/resources/ForUser.txt would search for /src in your file system (from root). a path starting with a dot is called relative. a relative path will always resolve itself based on the current working directory. in your case your working directory is "Project". so it looks for src in the folder Project. and so on. the following link provides some examples: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm

Comment: A path not starting with a / is relative, too. `.`just means "the current directory. `./foo/bar` is equivalent to `foo/bar`.

Comment: that is correct, forgot to mention that ^^

Comment: @TommySchmidt Thank you a lot for such a detailed explanation!